# Checkbox validation using React JS

Tags: reactjs, validation

I am currently working on a form having checkboxes which has to be validated using react JS. I need it to show an error saying 'Please select atleast 2 checkbox' if less than 2 checkboxes are checked. I've tried using the if condition but its not working. I have referred a lot of of websites but couldn't come up with a proper solution. Please do help me.

MY CODE:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkbox: "",
    checkboxValid: false,
    errorMsg: {},
  };

  validateForm = () => {
    const { checkboxValid } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      formValid: checkboxValid,
    });
  };

  updateCheckbox = (checkbox) => {
    this.setState({ checkbox }, this.validateCheckbox);
  };

  validateCheckbox = () => {
    const { checkbox } = this.state;
    let checkboxValid = true;
    let errorMsg = { ...this.state.errorMsg };
    if (checkbox.checked < 2) {
      checkboxValid = false;
      errorMsg.checkbox = "Please select atleast 2 checkbox";
    }
    this.setState({ checkboxValid, errorMsg }, this.validateForm);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="checkbox">checkbox</label>
        <ValidationMessage
          valid={this.state.checkboxValid}
          message={this.state.errorMsg.checkbox}
        />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target.value)}
        />
        Sports
        <br></br>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target.value)}
        />
        Business
        <br></br>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target.value)}
        />
        Health
        <br></br>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target.value)}
        />
        Society
        <br></br>
        <div>
          <button
            className="button"
            type="submit"
            disabled={!this.state.formValid}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are updating the same `checkbox` value in your state for every checkbox. You could have `checkbox` be an object instead, and have each of your checkboxes toggle a property on this object and then check how many properties are `true` when validating them.

Comment: Set the selected checkbox count in the state and use the count for validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define count in the state and update it based on the checkbox selection,

```
  state = {
    checkbox: "",
    checkboxValid: false,
    errorMsg: {},
    selectedCheckBox: 0
  };
```

Update Logic:-

```
updateCheckbox = ({ name, checked }) => {
    this.setState(
      (prev) => ({
        checkbox: checked,
        selectedCheckBox: checked
          ? prev.selectedCheckBox + 1
          : prev.selectedCheckBox - 1
      }),
      this.validateCheckbox
    );
  };
```

Use the `selectedCheckBox` count in the state for validation

Completed Code:-

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkbox: "",
    checkboxValid: false,
    errorMsg: {},
    selectedCheckBox: 0
  };

  validateForm = () => {
    const { checkboxValid } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      formValid: checkboxValid
    });
  };

  updateCheckbox = ({ name, checked }) => {
    this.setState(
      (prev) => ({
        checkbox: checked,
        selectedCheckBox: checked
          ? prev.selectedCheckBox + 1
          : prev.selectedCheckBox - 1
      }),
      this.validateCheckbox
    );
  };

  validateCheckbox = () => {
    const { checkbox } = this.state;
    let checkboxValid = true;
    let errorMsg = { ...this.state.errorMsg };
    if (this.state.selectedCheckBox < 2) {
      checkboxValid = false;
      errorMsg.checkbox = "Please select atleast 2 checkbox";
    }
    this.setState({ checkboxValid, errorMsg }, this.validateForm);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="checkbox">checkbox</label>
        {/* <ValidationMessage
          valid={this.state.checkboxValid}
          message={this.state.errorMsg.checkbox}
        /> */}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="business"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target)}
        />
        Sports
        <br></br>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="health"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target)}
        />
        Business
        <br></br>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="society"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target)}
        />
        Health
        <br></br>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) => this.updateCheckbox(e.target)}
        />
        Society
        <br></br>
        <div>
          <button
            className="button"
            type="submit"
            disabled={!this.state.formValid}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
          <br />
          <b style={{ fontSize: "30px" }}>{this.state.selectedCheckBox}</b>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-colden-8hdm4?file=/src/App.js:0-2160

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by having a different state for each checkbox. Set a name for each checkbox so that it can be access by e.target.name

Notice that the name of the input is the same as the state.

```
  state = {
    checkbox1: false,
    checkbox2: false,
    checkboxValid: false,
  };

  updateCheckbox = (e) => {
    this.setState({ e.target.name: e.target.checked });
  };

  if(this.state.checkbox1 && this.state.checkbox2) {
    //both are checked!
  }
```

change input to

```
<input
   name="checkbox1"
   type="checkbox"
   onChange={this.updateCheckbox}
   checked={this.state.checkbox1}
/>
```